# How can I update a string in C

Tags: c, string, sockets

So I have an array of strings. Im using this to send messages to the client.

```
char *server_msg[] = {"Welcome to the game!", "The sum is: ", "GO", "END", "ERROR"};
```

I want to be able to update [1] with the score so it would look like could look something like

```
{"The sum is: %d", player_sum}
```

I am sending messages to the clients like this eg to welcome the player to the game.

```
send(client_sockfd[i], server_msg[0], sizeof(server_msg), 0);
```

How could I append an int to that string is it possible? Or any tips on where to look.

Thank you.

Comment: Use `snprintf` and a temporary buffer

Comment: In this case you should keep the pointer array but switch out the string literals for dynamically allocated memory. This is very basic stuff that you need to know well before even considering socket programming and other more advanced topics.

Answer (score 3):

> How could I append an int to that string is it possible?

Modifying a string-literal isn't possible, since they are typically located in a read-only portion of the executable.

You could dynamically generate the string you want to send, though:

```
char buf[128];
int n = snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "The sum is: %i", sum);
send(client_sockfd[i], buf, n + 1, 0);  // +1 for the NUL terminator byte
```

Comment: +1: Just a note: the `snprintf` will return an `int` with the number of characters in the string (not including the `NULL` terminator), so you could save the `strlen` call.